# Lumen: Enable CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, lumen

I built an API with Lumen and want to access it with JavaScript and the XMLHttpRequest object. But every time my PUT, GET, POST, and DELETE requests are transformed into *OPTIONS - Request*. I read a lot of websites with information of CORS. I build middleware with the following content:

```
class CORSMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
      $response = null;
      /* Preflight handle */
      if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
         $response = new Response();
      } else {
         $response = $next($request);
      }

      $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
      $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
      $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      return $response;
    }
}
```

My client code:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/user";
var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpRequest.open('PUT', url, false);
xmlHttpRequest.send('{"username": "ABC", "password": "ABC","email": "mail@cool.xyz" }');
if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
  console.log(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
}
```

My request-information of GET request:

```
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

My response-information of a GET request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 27 Dec 2015 10:36:51 GMT
Host: localhost:8000
x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.0
```

My request-information of a PUT request:

```
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

My response information of a PUT request:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 27 Dec 2015 10:36:51 GMT
Host: localhost:8000
x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.0
```

In the preflight there are no "Access-Control-Allow-*"-Headers. I don't know why; I enabled it with my lumen-cors-middleware.

Comment: It sounds like your request is triggering the browser to first send [a CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). There’s no way to work around that; it’s required behavior in browsers with regard to cross-origin requests. So it seems like you may need to read up on the CORS docs and update your code accordingly.

Comment: On `PUT` AJAX requests and in many other cases browsers generate preflighted requests which you have tried to handle. What is your exact issue?

Comment: No POST, PUT or DELETE Request works - no response thats my issue :-) GET Requests are working

Comment: I already catch the preflight with the given php code..but it dont work why?

Answer (score 4):

Add following headers into public/.htaccess file.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
Header set  Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

this is working fine for to resolve Cross Origin Issue.

Comment: This works fine, and quick.. after I can create a middleware

Answer (score 3):

In `Lumen`, you need to setup `OPTIONS` routes manually for every `POST, PUT, DELETE...` routes.

This is what I did to resolve the problem.

```
$app->options('{all:.*}', ['middleware' => 'cors.options', function() {
    return response('');
}]);
```

The route above will catch all the `OPTIONS` requests for you.

In `cors.options` middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, DELETE')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Content-Type,X-CSRF-TOKEN')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
}
```

Comment: I built it in like written....but i can send GET-requests but my post, put, delete requests failed with 405 Method not allowed. All data for the http-request-header can you see here: http://pastebin.com/2Eks9Xqz

Comment: I'll got it in the way that my

Comment: Thanks man.. Seriously saved me.. Have been trying all the middlewares and all the library but your code did the work!