# HTTP 405 error in angular 5 post data to lumen

Tags: laravel-5, angular5, lumen

In my angular post data

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/exampledomain.com/public/postMethod',{title:'sample',method:'POST'},this.headers).subscribe(res => { this.candidateResponse = res.json(); console.log(res.json()); } );
```

Lumen

```
$router->post('postMethod', function (){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return json_encode(array("name"=>'sample'));
});
```

ERRORS:

405 (Method Not Allowed)

Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: Its use of server not allowing `OPTION` request you need to handle `CORS` you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476817/lumen-enable-cors

Comment: It's not solved.
header('Access-Control-Request-Methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type,X-CSRF-TOKEN');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Content-Type: multipart/form-data, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, text/plain');

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the cross origin issue,
1. You can add some code in your Laravel app
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/access-control-allow-origin-in-laravel-54/replies/392243
2. You can solve the issue with Angular also
3. You can add chrome extention